# How to understand isolate in Flutter? like Thread ? like Process?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, process, dart-isolates

Isolate is like a thread in Java, but the memory is not shared, also like a Linux process, but the function is more like Thread,how to understand it ?

Answer (score 0):

Isolate is Isolate like you are you
but it's explain
`independent workers that are similar to threads`
You perhaps saw this doc
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html